# java parsing array input control

Tags: java, parsing

Thanks for checking out my question.

Starting off, the program has the following goal; the user inputs currency formatted as "xD xC xP xH"; the program checks the input is correct and then prints back the 'long' version: "x Dollars, x Cents, x Penny's, x half penny's"

Here I have some code that takes input from user as String currencyIn, splits the string into array tokens, then replaces the D's with Dollars etc and prints the output.

```
public class parseArray
{

    public parseArray()
    {
        System.out.print('\u000c');
        String CurrencyFormat = "xD xS xP xH";
        System.out.println("Please enter currency in the following format: \""+CurrencyFormat+"\" where x is any integer");
        System.out.println("\nPlease take care to use the correct spacing enter the exact integer plus type of coin\n\n");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String currencyIn = input.nextLine();
        currencyIn.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("This is the currency you entered: "+currencyIn);

        String[] tokens = currencyIn.split(" ");

        for (String t : tokens)
        {   
         System.out.println(t);
        }
        String dollars = tokens[0].replaceAll("D", " Dollars ");
        String cents = tokens[1].replaceAll("C", " cents");
        String penny = tokens[2].replaceAll("P", " Penny's");
        String hPenny = tokens[3].replaceAll("H", " Half penny's");

        System.out.println(" "+dollars+ " " +cents+ " " +penny+ " " +hPenny);
        input.close();
    }
}
```

**Question 1:** At the moment the program prints out pretty anything you put in. how do I establish some input control? I've seen this done in textbooks with switch statement and a series of if statements, but were too complicated for me. Would it parse characters using charAt() for each element of the array?

**Question 2:** Is there a 'better' way to print the output? My friend said converting my 4 strings (dollars, cents, penny's, hpenny's) into elements 0, 1, 2, 3 of a new array (called newArray) and print like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: currencyIn.toUpperCase(); -> not work, you need to assign it back

Answer (score 1):

There is a neat solution, involving [Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) and some [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Core concept is that we define the input format through a regular expression. We need some sequence of digits, followed by a `'D'` or a `'d'`, followed by a `" "`, followed by a sequence of digits, followed by a `C` or `c`,... I will skip derivation of this pattern, it is explained in the regular expression tutorial I linked above. We will find that

```
final String regex = "([0-9]+)[D|d]\\ ([0-9]+)[C|c]\\ ([0-9]+)[P|p]\\ ([0-9]+)[H|h]";
```

satisfies our needs. With this regular expression we can now determine whether our `input` String has the right format ([`input.matches(regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)), as well as extract the bits of information we are actually interested in ([`input.replaceAll(regex, "$1 $2 $3 $4")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). Sadly, `replaceAll` yields another `String`, but it will contain the four digit sequences we are interested in, divided by a `" "`. We will use some stream-magic to transform this `String` into a `long[]` (where the first cell holds the `D`-value, the second holds the `C`-value,...). The final program looks like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        final String input = args[0];
        final String regex =
                "([0-9]+)[D|d]\\ ([0-9]+)[C|c]\\ ([0-9]+)[P|p]\\ ([0-9]+)[H|h]";

        if (input.matches(regex) == false) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input is malformed.");
        }

        long[] values = Arrays.stream(input.replaceAll(regex, "$1 $2 $3 $4").split(" "))
                .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
                .toArray();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
    }
}
```

If you want to have a `List<Long>` instead a `long[]` (or a `List<Integer>` instead of an `int[]`), you would use

```
        List<Long> values = Arrays.stream(input.replaceAll(regex, "$1 $2 $3 $4").split(" "))
                .map(Long::parseLong)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It is necessary to change `mapToLong` to `map` to receive a `Stream<Long>` instead of a [`LongStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html). I am sure that one could somehow write a custom [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) for `LongStream` to transform it into a `List<Long>`, but I found this solution more readable and reliable (after all, the `Collector` used comes from Oracle, I trust they test their code extensively).

Here is some example call:

```
$> java Test "10D 9c 8p 7H"
[10, 9, 8, 7]

$> java Test "10E 9C 8P 7H"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input is malformed.
        at Test.main(Test.java:10)

$> java Test "10D 9C 8P 7H 10D 9C 8P 7H"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input is malformed.
        at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It took me a few days to digest the new methods. I started a github page to display my code. I was still having some troubles, if you want to check out https://github.com/TiltedIntuition/CurrencyCalculator it has my code. Any feedback is greatly appreciated. The section is under the workInProgress branch.

Answer (score 0):

**Question1**

You can actually check if the input is what it's supposed to be with simple checks. For example, you can check the first element like this:

```
if(tokens[0].charAt(1).equals("D")) 
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Another way to check if the input is correct is by using [Regular Expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm), but I assume you are a beginner and this is too much trouble for you, although it is the better way. So I leave it to you to look through it later.

**Question2**

You can actually listen to your friend and do as they said. You can write it as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
   System.out.print(" " + tokens[i])

System.out.println();
```

Or you may use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

And you have saved `newArray` like this:

```
newArray[0] = " " + tokens[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. For q1, what if the x is a 3 digit integer? It not pick up because its not char 1 in tokens[0];?

Comment: I also get the error " char cannot be dereferenced"

Comment: @kp-a You can loop through each `tokens` and examine for the first occurrence of a non-digit character.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `.equals()` method to see if what a user has typed in matches what you have

```
if (currencyIn.equals("CurrencyFormat"))
{
 ...
}
```

this is probably the simplest way i can think of!

Comment: I fail to see how this is related to OP's question.